# Adding 2nd EIGRP route to Data Center

Tags: cisco, routing, router, eigrp, cisco-nexus

[image]

I am adding a 2nd layer 3 link between data centers using EIGRP. I want the remote sites to continue to use the 100 Mb to routes that are in Data Center 2 (unless the link is down).

If I'm correct the 200 Mb link from data center 1 then across would be a better metric. Can I use the `bandwidth` command on the Nexus interface to get the result I want?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can influence EIGRP routing with either the `bandwidth` or `delay` commands. In general, the `delay` command is preferred because the bandwidth command can change other things, e.g. QoS.

Comment: Bandwidth calculation in EIGRP is actually only concerned with the minimum value in a given path, while delay is additive.  Changing the local bandwidth value is meaningless to the calculation if the value is still greater than the slowest link.